# J2ME app to access incoming call - Where to start?

Tags: java, mobile, mobile-phones, java-me

Here's my requirement:

I often receive calls from unidentified numbers on my mobile phones. I would like an application which would use a reference list like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India), and show me the carrier name and the area of origin along with the number on screen.

- Mobile make : Sony Ericsson
- Model : C902
- Operating System: Propreitary
- J2ME: MIDP 2.0

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to do something like this? I have installed a lot of java apps on my mobile, and all of them have to be launched seperately, can be run in the background, but they never seem to access anything native.
2. If it is possible, which area of J2Me should I start with, for creating an application that achieves the above requirement?
3. If it is not possbile, what are my alternatives?

Comment: UPDATE: I found this app which partly does what I want: http://www.shaplus.com/mobile/. My question however pertains to doing the same in "real-time".

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. I dabbled in J2ME for a while, and came to the conclusion that it's <strike>basically just a big joke</strike> hard to do anything meaningful. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. can be run in the background? yes using Push Registry. access anything native? it depends on which native thing you want to access.
2. It is not possible.
3. On this model, you don't have alternatives, but on Symbian you can try Qt with help of Qt Mobility Project